# TChart - Append points in a specific point in series

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, teechart

How do you append/insert a point in specific point in an OHLC series?   Or more specifically, I want the newly added point the be the first point in the series.  Every new points that I add will become the first point in the series.

Using AddOHLC will insert it at the last point.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There's also an AddOHLC overload which lets you add a date so that you can choose where your values will be fitted in the series. This is the overload signature:

function AddOHLC(Const ADate: TDateTime; Const AOpen, AHigh, ALow, AClose: Double; Const ALabel: String; AColor: TColor): Integer; overload;